# Redis pipeline - atomic getting a value of another key value

Tags: python, redis

I have a string key named "a" and its value is "b", I also have a hash set which is named "b" and it has multiple values for example:

```
"a" (value equals to "b")

"b": {
       "first_name": "John",
       "last_name": "Doe"

}
```

is it possible to use a pipeline so given the key "a" I will receive
the object b value ?

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example of code snippet and the expected output? The question sounds interesting, but a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipeline is an optimization for sending multiple operations. It doesn't guarantee atomicity and the replies are available only after the pipeline is executed. That being the case, it would appear that it isn't suitable for what you're trying to do.

IIUC, you want to "dereference" the value in the first key and get the data in the second key. I suspect that when you use the term "atomically" your meaning is with one call to the server. That pattern isn't supported by Redis - instead, you should GET the value in `a` and then HMGET from `b`.

Answer (score 5):

Pipeline won't work, since you must wait until the first `get` command returns the *real key*, i.e. *b*.

Instead, you can achieve it with `lua scripts`.

```
local real_key = redis.call('get', KEYS[1])
if real_key then return redis.call('hgetall', real_key) end
```

The whole lua script executes atomically.